# [google-drive-sdk]: Can i upload entire folder to goolge drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Can i upload entire folder to google drive ? with out iterating file items in the folder ? I am able to upload single file by file from folder . But is there a way to upload entire folder in one go?

```
 def uploadToDrive(parentID, filePath, fileName, minetype): global google_service file_metadata = {
   'name': fileName,
   'parents': [parentID],
   'mimeType': minetype
 }
 print("ready to upload step 1") media = MediaFileUpload(filePath, mimetype = minetype, resumable = True) print("ready to upload step 2") file = google_service.files().create(body = file_metadata, media_body = media, fields = 'id').execute()
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: can you please show us what have you done. rather than asking vague questions

Comment: for file in os.listdir(FolderTobeUploaded):
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
             minetype = "application/pdf"
        else:
            minetype = "image/jpeg"
            
        filepath = FolderTobeUploaded + "/" + file
        fileQuery = "name contains " + "'" + file + "'"
        print(fileQuery)
        googlefileID = search_file(fileQuery)
        if googlefileID == -1:
            uploadToDrive(childfileID,filepath,file,minetype)

Comment: @ShobiPP please  find the code . def uploadToDrive(parentID,filePath,fileName,minetype):
    global google_service
 
    file_metadata = {
        'name': fileName,
        'parents': [parentID],
        'mimeType': minetype
    }
    print("ready to upload step 1")
    media = MediaFileUpload(filePath,
                            mimetype=minetype,
                            resumable=True)
    
    print("ready to upload step 2")
    file = google_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()

Comment: @ShobiPP the question wasn't vague. It was very specific and has a very specific answer, which is "no". Since what the OP wants to do is not possible, there is no code he can sensibly show. It's like Q:"can I jump across the grand canyon?" A:"What have you tried so far?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only upload one file at a time to Google Drive.  You will need to programmaticlly loop though each of the files in your directory and upload them one at a time.

You could use the [Batching](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) method to create the metadata, then run the uploads after.  However in my experience if batch fails then the full batch fails.  Note batching will not save you much as the quota is still counted for each request in the batch rather than as a single request.

Comment: Batch does not support  media uploads. It can only be used for metadata operations. Therefore it is *not* an option for the OP. Moreover, the batch does not succeed or fail. Rather each individual request succeeds or fails and the batch response is a multipart mime document with a part for each request indicating the success or failure of that request. Batch is nearly always a bad idea as it complicates the codebase with no benefit in return.

Comment: Batching supports the upload of the file metadata i have corrected the statement to be more clear.   In my experience if one item in the batch fails the full batch request fails.  I belive its in the documentation for the Google drive api i will see if i can find it.

Comment: from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch  "Google Drive does not support batch operations for media, either for upload" and "Response to a batch request: The server's response is a single standard HTTP response with a multipart/mixed content type; each part is the response to one of the requests in the batched request".

Batch achieves nothing towards the OP's requirement, and introduces unnecessary complications. Please remove it from your answer which is otherwise correct.

Comment: You do understand that there is a difference between uploading the file metadata and uploading the file itself right?  You can batch the metadata creation of the files then upload the actual file data to the metadata after.   I have actually done this.

Comment: Of course you can, but why would you? To do so adds an order of magnitude of complexity to the code, for absolutely zero benefit. The pseudo code to do individual uploads is `foreach file {upload metadata&content; doErrorHandling}`.  I invite you to update your answer with the pseudo-code to do that with a batch (including verifying that the batch size is viable, dealing with a filecount that could be zero or a multiple of batch size, or a non-multiple of batch size).

Comment: Using batches increases the probability of hitting 403 rate limits because the batch is unpacked in the front-end server and then each individual request is fired at Drive without any flow control. So all in all, Batch adds masses of complexity to the OP for zero benefit. Finally, your statement that an individual failure causes the batch to fail remains incorrect and will lead the OP down the wrong path for his error handling. For these reasons I am forced to downvote your answer. I'll happily turn that into an upvote for the first part of your answer once you remove the Batch suggestion.